# multiple regression or multiple step wise regression

Tags: regression

I am studying the correlation between principal efficacy, leadership and collective teacher efficacy.  How do I analyze the data from the three surveys will administer?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated. To get a useful answer you will need to provide a good deal more detail about the nature and scope of your data and the hypotheses that you wish to test.

Comment: Here are the research questions.

Comment: 1. Is there s correlation between principal efficacy and leadership?

Comment: 2.  Is there a correlation between leadership and collective teacher efficacy?

Comment: 3.  Is there a correlation between principals efficacy and collective teacher efficacy?

Comment: Data will be collected using three Likert lie surveys.